# Como fazer o switch voltar ao estado "falso"?

Tags: java, android

Eu criei um switch que liga e desliga o bluetooth. Porem, ao ligar, ele pergunta ao usuario se ele realmente quer ativar o bluetooth. Se o usuario clicar no nao, o switch continua ativo e o app crusha.

Alguem sabe como fazer o Switch voltar a posição inicial caso o usuario clique em nao ?

estou usando On checked, como abaixo:

```
comum.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // Ligado
        } else {
            // Desligado
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, sou novo por aqui.

Comment: `buttonView.isChecked = false`. Tenha em conta que isso, eventualmente, irá fazer que o método `onCheckedChanged()` seja chamado novamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, faz sentido, valeu mesmo !!!